# Convert Date Types in Typescript

Tags: c, angular, date, typescript

So I'm getting Data from a C# Rest-Server. One value of the array is of the type Date. When I want to calculate with it for example:

```
let difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
```

I get the following error:

> date1.getTime is not a function

I guess the error is, that `Date` of Java is not the same as Date of  Typescript.

Is there a way to convert a value of type `Date` (Java) to type `Date` (TypeScript)?

Or I'm I wrong and the error is caused by something else?

Comment: It depends what format the date is sent over REST. Is it ms since epoch or a string formatted zoned date time??

Comment: You guess right, the Java Date is not related with the TypeScript Date. But you can use the raw / primitiv data to convert from one to another. For example, instead of transmitting the Date object, transmitt the Date.getTime() to transmit the millisecond value. In TypeScript you can create a new Date with those millis.

Comment: or you may use moment library for parsing the date https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-moment
it is not dependent upon formatting even c# or python it works well with all environment and may help further for difference zone convert and many more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert the date to Date Object inorder to apply its method.

```
let difference = new Date(date1).getTime() - new Date(date2).getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON has no date object. Usually a string is sent, take a closer look at what your API  is providing. Sometimes it is a timestamp - depending on your GSON/Jackson/.. configuration. Timestamp needs a timezone offset too, therefore I'd prefer a string based format with included time zone. Usually it looks like this: `"2018-03-10T09:06:08.068Z"`

You can read this string into a JavaScript Date by passing it into the constructor: `new Date(dateString)`. Now you have access to the methods.

Void already posted a vanilla JS implementation, but it gets even easier if you use a lib for that. I'd highly recommend date-fns. It accepts strings, so there is no need to create a new date:

`differenceInMilliseconds(dateLeft, dateRight)`

Docs:
https://date-fns.org/v1.29.0/docs/differenceInMilliseconds

Answer (score 0):

console.log((new Date().getTime() < new Date("2022-02-03").getTime()).toString());

This is how we do in Typescript

Comment: Make sure to pass the second date in yyyy-mm-dd format